# Change the axis name seaborn plot from value/variable

Tags: pandas, seaborn, axis, names

[image]I am working on a dataframe that consists of multiple of columns that corresponds to different part of the drive (e.g. right turn, left turn, etc.) and rows that correspond to driver's id. Overall, I want to plot the values of all the different columns. My code is here and is successful except of one aspect: the displayed names on the x,y axes are not the ones I want.

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="variable", y="value", data=pd.melt(mvel))
sns.set_palette("muted")
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=70)
plt.savefig('mvel_6turntypes.png', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
```

So x, y axes names are value and variable. I want to change these names to correspond to my data.

Comment: Can you show your plot image? I believe you are talking about `ylabel` and `xlabel` but i'm note sure

Comment: So why not use the name you want in [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)?

Comment: @Terry yes, what you 're assuming is correct. I added the plot on my initial post. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I didn't know about this option but it doesn't work. I added the following: `data=pd.melt(mvel, var_name='Average speed (mph)', value_name='Parts')` and the error is `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'variable'`

Comment: `ax = sns.boxplot(x="variable", y="value", data=pd.melt(mvel)).set(
    xlabel='Parts', 
    ylabel='Average speed (mph)' )
sns.set_palette("muted")
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=70)
plt.savefig('mvel_6turntypes.png', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')`. This also adds the x, labels that I want but disables the part of the code that rotates the xticks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To change the labels you can do by:

**Setting direct to the plot**

```
plt.xlabel('Average speed (mph)')
plt.ylabel('Parts')
```